# Windows Defender Application Guard has no internet access

Tags: internet, windows-11, microsoft-edge, windows-defender

We are testing the use of Windows Defender Application Guard. It is enabled, and I can access it through the Edge Settings menu, but once on the application guard edge browser we seem to get no internet.

We use a proxy and vpn on a windows 11 machine. It is auto detecting our vpn info, which shows correctly in edge://application-guard-internals. I have tried using the applicationguardcontainerproxy registry key to no avail.

Can't seem to figure anything out, and I do not see alot about an issue when running a google search.

Any thoughts? Anyone having similar issue?

Comment: Turn off VPN and Proxy, restart, check Internet and then call VPN Support number.